# Generic type to datatable on C#

Tags: c#, generics, datatable

I want to use a generic class which I created

```
public class ClienteleReport<TClientSource>
{        
    private TClientSource _clients { get; set; }
    private SqlCntr _conn { get; set; }

    public ClienteleReport(TClientSource clients, SqlCntr conn)
    {
        _clients = clients;
        _conn = conn;
    }

    public void LoadDataForReport(string[] filter, string order = "asc", int returnTop = -1)
    {

    }

}
```

when I instantiate the class I pass as parameters the datatable object and the database connection object to it.

Once done I want to use the `LoadDataForReport` method to perform filtering and various other functions. How can I handle `_clients` as a datatable ? and If possible, how can I return a `Datatable` object ?

The code that invokes the generic class is listed below

```
    private SqlCntr _conn;        
    public ClientReportForm(DataTable clients, SqlCntr conn)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (conn == null)
        {
            return;                
        }

        _conn = conn;

        var ClientReportObj = new ClienteleReport<DataTable>(clients, _conn);

        ClientReportObj.LoadDataForReport(new[] {""}, "asc");
    }
```

I'm writing an application for spare parts management which includes warehouse and clientele. The code above has to do with reporting. I want to create a report which filters the original data passed as a parameter.

The logic behind it is to return a filtered data object (99% of the time will be a DataTable) but I want to use generics in order to be able to use it with other data sources like text files, JSON, XML etc.

The clients object is a DataTable and the _conn object is the database connection object, which will perform the insert,delete,update functions and many more that I've implemented.

I think that's better now in terms of explaining what I want to do. If you need any further detail, please let me know.

Comment: You have some ideas in your mind and, without showing your attempt, you want us to write it for you?

Comment: what do you mean show my attempt ? I've just started writing this and I've never used generics before. I've watched some tutorials and I didn't quite understood it. That's why i ask. What details would you like me to provide ?

Comment: Try to write what you have in your mind, if you get stuck at a *spesific* point ask it. This is how SO works. Your question is *too broad* in this form

Comment: @Tony please post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating your question. Be more specific. E.g. instead of "how to use generics with my database" ask "when I do X, I expect Y, but get Z. Why, and how to get Y?"

Comment: OK. First things first....I'm writing an application that will handle car parts warehouse, clientele, etc....I want to implement reporting. The logic behind it, is that no matter the data source (DataTable, TXT file, etc) It will handle the data (hence Generics) and will return an appropriate object (99% of the times it will be a data table. I will post the code where I call the function and describe the logic there.

Comment: I've updated the original post and i think its more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the solution is to use constraints like the following

```
public class ClienteleReport<TClientSource> where TClientSource : DataTable
```

thank you for your time.